# Downloading and starting MapServer4Windows

Tags: mapserver, installation, osgeo4w, ms4w

I am new to web mapping and am trying to use MapServer For Windows. While I have found tutorials I have been unable to even install the program.

I have updated to the most recent LTR version of QGIS and its associated programs, as I was under the assumption that I needed OSGeo4W to run MS4W. However, I am still having issues accessing MS4W.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please take the  [tour] to learn how to ask a focussed question. As it stands, your question is too broad and rather unclear.

Comment: Download MS4W, unzip into c:\, open command window, go to c:\ms4w\apache\bin and run `httpd`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mix up OSGEo4W and MS4W. These are different packages for Windows. OSGeo4W is a source for several FOSS4G project, among other MapServer and QGIS. MS4W contains programs, tools necessary to run/maintain a MapServer instance on Windows (Apache, Mapserver, Mapserver utilities, several libraries). You can use any of them but do not mix them up.